# How to access validation data in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

So there's an argument called `validation_split` once used with 0.1 or something, Keras automatically split the data provided in x,y argument. My question is: how can I put my hands on the result of this split? In particular I want the test data (x_test, and y_test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [keras' documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) in `validation_split` argument -

> The validation data is selected from the last samples in the x and y
>   data provided, before shuffling.

So you can access validation data as described below -

```
import math

test_split_ratio = 0.1
test_x = x[-math.ceil(len(x)*test_split_ratio):]
test_y = y[-math.ceil(len(x)*test_split_ratio):]
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't you think it is wiser to shuffle then split? I see that you replicated what Keras is internally doing, I was hoping to get it for free, after all, that's the whole point is to enjoy being lazy and depends on these convenient methods.

Comment: Actuallly there is a method for this purpose. It's available in [sklearn library](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). But you can't get the split from the ```fit``` function because it only returns training history.